# Check that a SPARK Dataframe column matches a Regex for all occurrences using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using Scala.

I have a dataframe with a column `date` which looks like that:

```
|            date             |
|2017-09-24T11:05:52.647+02:00|
|2018-09-24T11:05:52.647+02:00|
|2018-10-24T11:05:52.647+02:00|
```

I have a regex to check the date format:

```
pattern = new regex(([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|    [12]\d|3[01])T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}\+\d{2}:\d{2}))
```

I want to check if each row in the dataframe matches with the regex, if yes return true and if not return false. I need to return just true or false not a list.

Any help is welcome and many thanks for your help.

Comment: Unclear --> do you want a result true or false per row / entry? Or if any deviation found, 1 or more, of in fact first, then return false, else true?

Comment: true => if all rows matches with regex // and False => if only 1 rows is false

Comment: ok, not surd why a minus one given, as seems good q

Comment: I m doing that but it s not working : var teste = true;
    val res = df.foreach(r => if (pattern.findFirstIn(r.toString()).isEmpty) {testt = false}    );
    println("teste  : " + teste)

Comment: Seems like you need EXISTS with regex. Not sure if possible

Comment: I just looked for Exists, it doesn't exist :)

Comment: It was more figure of speech, because something like that is req'd, I will have a think

Comment: EXISTS does exist, not that this is the answer val res = spark.sql("SELECT 1 FROM XYZ WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cityid FROM XYZ where cityid = 0)") , just to prove the point

Comment: But I think first or findFirst should be a goer

Comment: pls indicate if you have been helped

Comment: You state thanks for your help. Could you state if you were helped by the answer pls?

Answer (score 1):

This should work - but turning it around, find first non-match:

```
import scala.util.Try
val result = Try(Option(df.filter($"cityid" rlike "[^0-9]").first)).toOption.flatten
if (result.isEmpty) { println("Empty")}
```

I use a DF as outcome and you can just check if empty or not.

Please tailor to your own situation. e.g. not empty, your own regex.

Without the Try and such the .first generates an error if empty. None is returned if empty and you can do the empty check.